# showQuickActionVfHeader

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to use showQuickActionVfHeader save button in visualforce Page?

The idea is to add an action to the button to attach the pdf to the opportunity.

[image]

Comment: Without adding code it would not be possible to be of any help. Please add some context and also add code that is not working.

Comment: There is no code snippet because I just want to see if it is possible to add action to this button, the documentation does not specify how to use it

Comment: [Others](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4RqMSAV) wondered before.